# Can I increase the draw distance in Warhammer 40k: Dawn of War?

Tags: warhammer-40k-dawn-of-war

When playing with the camera in *Warhammer 40k Dawn of War: Dark Crusade*, I can't help but notice the shallow draw distance. The game is quite old, and this might have made sense back when PCs were less powerful, but it would be nice to see more of the battlefield in the modern day.

This is what I currently see:

[image: shallow draw distance]

There doesn't seem to be any in-game settings to increase the draw distance or reduce the fog. Is there a config file or something I can edit to increase the draw distance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following mod: **[Increase Fog Distance and Sky radius](https://www.moddb.com/mods/increased-fog-distance-sky-radius/downloads)***.

To install it:

- Grab the specific mod for the version of the game you're playing (in my case, this is the 'DC' or 'Dark Crusade' version)
- Download and extract the `.zip` file.
- Follow the included instructions to place the mod in the correct folder. In my case, I had to copy the 'Data' folder to:

  ```
  {steam_directory}/steamapps/common/Dawn of War Dark Crusade/DXP2
  ```

This is what it looks like with the mod installed:

[image: No fog of war and increased draw distance]

---

<sub>* I have no affiliation to this mod or the team surrounding it.</sub>